# How do I extract data from "List" field

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I'm getting JSON data from webservice and trying to make a table . `Datadisk` is presented as `List` and clicking into each item will navigate further down the hiearchy like denoted in screenshots below. I need to concatate `storageAccountType` for each item with `|` sign, so if there were 2 list items for Greg-VM and it had `Standard_LRS` for first one and `Premium_LRS` for second one then new column will list `Standard_LRS | Premium_LRS` for that row. 
Input returned by function is below

```
[
  {
    "name": "rhazuremspdemo",
    "disk": {
      "id": "/subscriptions/24ba3e4c-45e3-4d55-8132-6731cf25547f/resourceGroups/AzureMSPDemo/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/rhazuremspdemo_OsDisk_1_346353b875794dd4a7a5c5938abfb7df",
      "storageAccountType": "StandardSSD_LRS"
    },
    "datadisk": []
  },
  {
    "name": "w12azuremspdemo",
    "disk": {
      "id": "/subscriptions/24ba3e4c-45e3-4d55-8132-6731cf25547f/resourceGroups/AzureMSPDemo/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/w12azuremspdemo_OsDisk_1_09788205f8eb429faa082866ffee0f18",
      "storageAccountType": "Premium_LRS"
    },
    "datadisk": []
  },
  {
    "name": "Greg-VM",
    "disk": {
      "id": "/subscriptions/24ba3e4c-45e3-4d55-8132-6731cf25547f/resourceGroups/GREG/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/Greg-VM_OsDisk_1_63ed471fef3e4f568314dfa56ebac5d2",
      "storageAccountType": "Premium_LRS"
    },
    "datadisk": [
      {
        "name": "Data",
        "createOption": "Attach",
        "diskSizeGB": 10,
        "managedDisk": {
          "id": "/subscriptions/24ba3e4c-45e3-4d55-8132-6731cf25547f/resourceGroups/GREG/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/Data",
          "storageAccountType": "Standard_LRS"
        },
        "caching": "None",
        "toBeDetached": false,
        "lun": 0
      },
      {
        "name": "Disk2",
        "createOption": "Attach",
        "diskSizeGB": 10,
        "managedDisk": {
          "id": "/subscriptions/24ba3e4c-45e3-4d55-8132-6731cf25547f/resourceGroups/GREG/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/Disk2",
          "storageAccountType": "Standard_LRS"
        },
        "caching": "None",
        "toBeDetached": false,
        "lun": 1
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

How do I do that?
Thanks,
G

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This should help you. It steps through the process.

If you have a scenario like this

[image]

you can use `Add custom Column` and type the follwing expression:

```
=Table.Columns([TableName], "ColumnName")
```

to get it as list:

[image]

Now you can left click on the `Custom` column and chose `Extract Values...`.

[image]

Choose `Custom` and your delimiter `|` and hit `OK`

[image]

This way the data who was in your list will now be in the same row with the delimiter

[image]

Comment: Problem for me is that Values in this list is buried several objects below as you can see from original screenshot, so I can not extract values directly

Comment: I added JSON input above